# Show/Refresh Button working properly

Tags: c#, winforms, button, refresh

I have a checkbox in `form1`, when it is checked it makes a `PictureBox` in `form2` visible but when I uncheck I want to refresh `form2` so that the `PictureBox` is not visible. This code is in `form1`. It is a button that opens up the form if one if not open but if a form is open it refreshes it. The problem is that it is not refreshing. Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
private tuesday _FavoritesForm;

public void startbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_FavoritesForm == null)
    {
        _FavoritesForm = new tuesday();
        _FavoritesForm.Closed += new EventHandler(_FavoritesForm_Closed);
        _FavoritesForm.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        _FavoritesForm.Refresh();
    }
```

}

Comment: *The button checks if a form is open, if it is not open the it opens one. This is to avoid multiple forms being opened at once. Then if a form is already open, it refreshes it, but it is not repainting form2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add a public method on the secondary form to Show/Hide the picture because it appears the second form has no idea of the first form.  Then the click / checkbox setting on the first form to instead of doing a "REFRESH" on the second, create the form if its not already done so.  Once created, call whatever method you expose on the secondary form to specifically make visible or not as needed.

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION

@a13xy, actually the reverse... The second form has no idea of the first, but yes, have a method that is public on the 2nd.  Then on the FIRST form, in the click / value changed event of your checkbox, you just call the method from that... such as your sample code...

```
    public void startbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
      if (_FavoritesForm == null)     
      {  _FavoritesForm = new tuesday();         
         _FavoritesForm.Closed += new EventHandler(_FavoritesForm_Closed);
         _FavoritesForm.Show();     
      }     
      else     
      {  _FavoritesForm.Refresh(); 
      } 

      _FavoritesForm.ShowHide( IsCurrentForms.CheckBox.IsCheckedValue );
   }
```

Not positive of your checkbox controls name, or its Checked value property, just call the second form's method directly with whatever your forms value is and the method in the SECOND form could be something like...

```
public void ShowHide( Boolean ShowTheImage )
{
    // value provided as a direct parameter from the first form, 
    // THISform knows about its own Picture property and can directly
    // set the visibility within its scoped control.
    this.YourPicture.Visible = ShowTheImage  
}
```

Comment: Okay, i think i understand what you are saying...I just need a little help writing it. So i'll create the public method on the second form called showhide, which will check if the checkboxes on the first form are checked or not, but how would i get it to continuously check & make the pictureboxes on the second form show/hide. What is the code?
Sorry i'm completely new at this and don't really know much. Still trying to understand everything.

Answer (score 3):

Calling Refresh on a form merely forces it to be repainted.  There isn't any reason to assume that it will repaint differently.  You would have to override the OnPaint() method in that form.  Clearly you are not using OnPaint to draw an image, you are using a PictureBox.  Setting that control's Visible property to false will make the image disappear, no additional help is needed.

Comment: The check box is on form1 and the pictureBox is on form2.

Comment: Yes, that's what I assumed when I wrote this answer.